# How to copy XML and add to existing text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm struggling with an XML file in which I need to add some curly braces. I'm already using XSLT (1.0) to generate the XML file. The only characters that are missing are the { } around a value in the XML file.

The source file looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<container>
  <pan>
    <id>1</id>
    <input>
      <url>thisfile-1.xml</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>thisoutput-1.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
  <pan>
    <id>2</id>
    <input>
      <url>anotherfile-2.xml</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>oldoutput-2.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
  <pan>
    <id>3</id>
    <input>
      <url>alsofile-3.xml</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>newoutput-3.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
</container>
```

The variable I need to change is in container/pan/input/url
The resulting file should look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<container>
  <pan>
    <id>1</id>
    <input>
      <url>{thisfile-1.xml}</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>thisoutput-1.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
  <pan>
    <id>2</id>
    <input>
      <url>{anotherfile-2.xml}</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>oldoutput-2.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
  <pan>
    <id>3</id>
    <input>
      <url>{alsofile-3.xml}</url>
    </input>
    <output>
      <url>newoutput-3.txt</url>
    </output>
  </pan>
</container>
```

The url's are variable and only the input url should be changed not the output url.

I tried some string replacement examples but they are actually replacing the content, I want to preserve the content and adding the braces only.
Any ideas would be appreciated, I'm on a dead end right now.

The XSLT I'm using now is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="input/url/text()">
    <xsl:text>replacetext</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This only replaces the input url ....
This is as far as my knowledge about XSLT goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have everything set up well.  Just change

```
<xsl:text>replacetext</xsl:text>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('{', ., '}')"/>
```

to wrap the existing `input/url` text (`.`) with `{` and  `}` as requested.

### XSLT

Here's the full XSLT, which you wisely based on the identity transformation, plus the above fix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="input/url/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('{', ., '}')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah great, did not know the concat() function, very good, that worked like a charm, thank you very very much. You saved my day !